# Weird UserControl image path behaviour in Blend 4 and WPF 4.0

Tags: wpf, image, resources, path

I'm using Blend 4 and VisualStudio 2010 to build a kiosk WPF 4.0 app that has a wizard-like function. I've decided I'd like individual steps moved to separate UserControls, to keep the main window of the application as lean as possible. However, I'm having trouble including the UserControl into the main window, since image paths are being mangled after moving the XAML to a separate UserControl file.

This code works when it's put into the main window XAML:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{DynamicResource ImageButton}">
  <Button.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Extra/motor_boat_2.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
  </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

But when I move that code to a separate user control and include it in the main window, the designer throws and exception:

> IOException: Cannot locate resource 'images/extra/sailing_boat.jpg'.

I've tried using a couple of different syntaxes, but all fail, sometimes using the `%ProgramFiles%` directory, other times converting the absolute path to relative (as above). Sometimes, the Build Project operation in Blend 4 fails because of this.

All the images are marked as **Resource** with Build Action set to **Copy Always**.

VisualStudio has no problem building and running the application, the UserControl displays correctly within the running application with no thrown exceptions.

**EDIT:**

Using relative paths in the UserControl and then building and running the app from VisualStudio and switching back to Blend correctly displays the images, until the next modification to the UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) like following:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Extra/motor_boat_2.jpg");
```

Comment: That was the first form of paths I tried, didn't help. It showed up correctly in VS, but not in Blend. I've edited the question to include a case where it did work.